# How to set List<Object[]> to HQL parameter?

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

Here is my code I want to execute:

```
Query query = getSession().createQuery("select count(*),uv.voter.gender from UserVoter uv  where " +
            "  uv.voter.age between "+startAge+" and "+endAge+" and uv.hamlet.hamletId = :hamletId  group by uv .voter.gender  ") ;
    //query.setParameter("publicationDateId",publicationDateId);
    query.setParameter("hamletId", hamletId);
      return query.list();
```

The following are cases for the start and end parameters:

```
18-25
25-35
35-45
```

for these 3 cases I have to run the query 3 times. I want to get the results in one query for the above three cases. I have an idea about `new map()`  but how can I do that?

The output should map to a pair of input parameters like:

`18-25,55,male 18-25,56,female 25-35,44,male..`

in mysql i achive this

```
select concat(18,'to',25),count( v.voter_id),v.gender from voter v join  user_voter u on v.voter_id = u.voter_id
where v.age between 18 and 25 and u.hamlet_id=10 group by v.gender
union
select concat(26,'to',35),count( v.voter_id),v.gender from voter v join  user_voter u on v.voter_id = u.voter_id
where v.age between 26 and 35 and u.hamlet_id=10 group by v.gender
union
select concat(36,'to',50),count( v.voter_id),v.gender from voter v join  user_voter u on v.voter_id = u.voter_id
where v.age between 36 and 50 and u.hamlet_id=10 group by v.gender
union
select concat(51,'to',200),count( v.voter_id),v.gender from voter v join  user_voter u on v.voter_id = u.voter_id
where v.age between 51 and 200 and u.hamlet_id=10 group by v.gender;
```

but how to get that effect in hibernate without using native sql?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should also use parameters for startAge and endAge.

Then you can generate the needed other conditions in your string used to make a Query using a for loop on your cases wich will give you something like:

```
(uv.voter.age between :startAge0 and :endAge0) or (uv.voter.age between :startAge1 and :endAge1) ...
```

You can easily generate the following string and then add the parameters using namedParameters.
You may have a look if you don't prefer positioned parameter for this case (using '?' and then setting the parameters using an index.

Comment: for loop also runs times and interacts with 3 times with database

Comment: you don't execute the query, but construct the string query with 3 conditions using the for loop.

Comment: i want map output like this

Answer (score 0):

You can't do what you want with a single call to the database. If you really want to hit the database only once then I think your best option is :

```
select uv.voter.age, uv.voter.gender, count(*) from UserVoter uv where uv.hamlet.hamletId = :hamletId group by uv.voter.age, uv.voter.gender
```

This will give you (18,male,5) (18,female,4) (19,male,3) (19,female,6) ...

Then you can group the results programmatically.

Comment: can i  achieve that  using db procedures or functions